# Cannot assign to a read-only property

Tags: database, delphi, runtime

I'm trying to change the database and the tablename against a TTable component during run time, however this error keeps appearing at this line:

```
  E2129 Cannot assign to a read-only property
```

The code I am trying to use is as follows:

```
  tblDest.Database  := lvDestAlias;
  tblDest.TableName := lvDestAlias;
```

The variables in use are strings that have previously been initialised. So yeah if you could help in anyway I would appreciate it :)

Comment: Database is a read-only property

Comment: As previously mentioned by "RRUZ", you should use "DatabaseName". However, I understand your confusion, the idea of "read-only" or  "write only" properties is weird, wheter Delphi, C# or other languages, and in that case, should be more like a function, or a property that can be read & write. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your problem is in the [`Database`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Bde.DBTables.TDBDataSet.Database) property which is read-only,  you must set the [`DatabaseName`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Bde.DBTables.TDBDataSet.DatabaseName) property instead.